# Does anyone knows how to use root access in B4a?

Tags: android, root, basic4android

Actually, I mean when an app has root permission, all its (dangerous) permissions run without limitation ?

EG : Call Recorder-Skvalex. I found C codes in This app , Google has blocked or restricted third-party applications from accessing the permissions required for call recording such as:

*android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS

android.permission.READ_CONTACTS*

Also, Audio source (Voice_call) ( not sure!) in android 9 (Pie).

But if device is rooted, this app able to record call perfectly (both side voice).

Question is what actually happens? In addition, is it possible to publish apps with this kind of permissions in play store anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

if the phone is root then maybe you can do these things you want,but after Android 6.0 you should use runtime permissions and also in the market such as **PlayStore** you should have reason for using this permission.

android.permission.READ_CONTACTS is accessible with runtime permissions without ROOT ! good luck.